# Is the diff algorithm for post titles broken?

Tags: bug, review-queues, diff

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57642442/5951320)'s original title is:

> Problem in Ionic 4 with asycronity when making a http post, how to wait?

but this is what [the Suggested Edits page](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/23881611) looks like:

[image]

which would suggest to me that the original title was (with difference in bold):

> Problem in Ionic 4 with asyncronity when making a http post, how **with post** to wait?

As such, I can't be sure what the suggested title is, so I can't review the edit.

Is this a bug with the Suggested Edits page, or what?

Disabling SOX doesn't help, but I do get the [correct diff](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYlXM.png) (thanks @rene) if I use incognito mode.

Comment: I don't see the extra "with post" when I click on https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/23881611

Comment: This is what I see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYlXM.png and I think that is clear what changed?